# The variable I send to the view with response is blank

Tags: json, laravel-5, view, controller, response

I'm retrieving data from the database in the controller via the query and trying to send it to view using response-> json, but the view da console looks empty  {}

Controller

```
 public function hamleler($mac_id,$turnuva_sporcu_id){

    $notations=array();
    $notations=Notasyon::select('id','beyaz_hamle')- 
   >where('mac_id',$mac_id)->where('turnuva_sporcu_id',$turnuva_sporcu_id)
        ->orderby('id','desc')
        ->first();
        //->pluck('beyaz_hamle');
    return response()->json($notations);
   }
```

canli.blade

```
 $.get("{{URL::To('/{turnuva_sporcu_id}/{mac_id}/canli-yayin/hamleler')}}", function(data1) {
     if(data1) {
               console.log(data1);
             }
                else {
                alert('error');
                }

                 });
```

data in console screen
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to print the $notations value in the controller to check whether your are getting any result from the model or not.

**dd($notations)**  : 
this would print the result retrieved from the *Notasyon* model.

Also check the spelling of Notasyon...it might be Notation...I think..

Comment: i did and i saw this output ` Notasyon {#202 ▼
  #table: "notasyon"
  #connection: "mysql"
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: array:2 [▶]
  #original: array:2 [▶]
  #changes: []
  #casts: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: []
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #fillable: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▶]
}`